# Really simple immutable class

Tags: c#, immutability

I have a `User` entity. Each instance of the `User` class should have a first name, surname and email, and these shall never be assigned values aside from during their initialisation, since they should never change (in the context of my code).

```
public class User
{
    private string _firstName, _surname, _email;

    public string FirstName => _firstName;
    public string Surname => _surname;
    public string Email => _email;

    public User(string firstName, string surname, string email)
    {
        _firstName = firstName;
        _surname = surname;
        _email = email;
    }
}
```

As simple as it is, I'd like a quick review of the above since it's how I've started coding up all of my classes in favour of immutability (unless a particular class' property is subject to change).

For example, do you feel I should be using `readonly` instead? Or some other access modifier?

Also, are there any opinions on how I've declared multiple variables on one line (the privates)?

Comment: @200_success - I'm not convinced that edit was necessary. 'user' doesn't really provide any relevant context to this review. It is a `User` class, but it's with regard to any immutable class at all.

Comment: Think about the long term health of the site. I'm trying to preempt title collisions for the next decade.

Comment: By the way, in C♯ 8, your entire class may eventually end up looking like this: `class User(string FirstName, string Surname, string Email)`.

Comment: @200_success - surely then my title was not specific enough? Either that or future questions are duplicates? I'm just not convinced the reference to the 'user' context is the right way to make this specific enough. I'm willing to concede, you're more experienced in the management of content than I, just wanted to provide some feedback that's all.

Comment: @JörgWMittag - wow! I'm curious to know more about that.

Answer (score 36):

Make it **simpler**, you can use read-only properties:

```
public class User
{
    public string FirstName { get; }
    public string Surname { get; }
    public string Email { get; }

    public User(string firstName, string surname, string email)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        Surname = surname;
        Email = email;
    }
}
```

Now let's consider to make it **closed**, I do not see any *extension point* then if you don't have any other requirement against this you should also mark it as not inheritable:

```
public sealed class User
```

What next? Make it **safer**. Your class and its ctor are public then you should validate parameters:

```
public User(string firstName, string surname, string email)
{
    if (firstName == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(firstName));

    if (surname == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(surname));

    if (email == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(email));

    FirstName = firstName;
    Surname = surname;
    Email = email;
}
```

If you're using C#7 then consider to use throw exceptions (see [pgerchev's](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/161825/really-simple-immutable-user-class/161826#comment307128_161826) comment and [t3schb0t](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/161883/13424)'s answer).

Class has not to be public? Remove `public` from its declaration. Constructor is not intended to be called outside your own assembly but class has to be public? Mark ctor as `internal` and assert  about its arguments.

Note about `Debug.Assert`: obviously this does not mean you won't need to validate *somewhere* these arguments ([see also comments](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/161825/really-simple-immutable-class#comment307161_161826)) when building in release mode, just that here you assume they're right. See also [Exception Vs Assertion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1276318/1207195), consider pre/post-conditions not an alternative to validation but - sort of - run-time unit testing:

```
internal User(string firstName, string surname, string email)
{
    Debug.Assert(firstName != null);
    Debug.Assert(surname != null);
    Debug.Assert(email != null);

    FirstName = firstName;
    Surname = surname;
    Email = email;
}
```

Do you need any other validation (`email` has not to be empty and it has to be a valid e-mail address, for example)? Add them all there. Be careful with people's name validation (see David's [linked post](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)).

Anything else? Make it **easier to debug**:

```
[DebuggerDisplay("{FirstName} {Surname} ({Email})")]
public sealed class User
```

Last note: yes, there is an `[ImmutableObject]` attribute you may use to decorate your class but AFAIK it's used only by `PropertyGrid` control. You may add it as reminder (for you or for future readers) that class has to be immutable but nothing else.

Comment: Note that in C# 7.0 you can simplify the properties validation even further like this.  `FirstName = firstName ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(firstName));`. Same applies for the other properties as well of course.

Comment: This really is an excellently concise and thorough answer. I didn't think I'd get such informative feedback on a code review this small and simple. Well played.

Comment: Jay, small snippets are always easier to review! ;)

Comment: You might also want to reconsider splitting FirstName and Surname, http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: @DavidTheWin that's a must-see! It's the reason I avoided to comment about _other validations_ on FirstName and Surname properties, I felt little bit overthinking to introduce the topic here but a link to that page is always pretty welcome! Thank you

Comment: Perfect post, but don't agree at all on the Debug.Assert. Debug.Assert works (by default) only in debug builds, and it's scope is to help during debug. When your code is encountering an unexpected situation the standard and expected behaviour is to raise an exception, no matters if it's an internal, public, or private class, because you need to manage the condition. Your use of asserts instead seems to imply "I will never meet this condition in release because I've already tested every possible situation during debug", that means that the code will crash at the first chance when in production.

Comment: @moto it's exactly why I'm using Debug.Assert(), I expect errors on private classes during debugging because I'm checking everything on component's boundaries (public classes, I/O). Assertions are then 1) informative about required preconditions; 2) a defense to avoid _mistaken_ validations during development; 3) an aid to complement all my tests. Note that as usual there isn't a _rule_ then you may end-up, for example, validating inputs on a private method because it's called by 5 public ones.

Comment: With over-defensive programming (IMO!) you just pay the performance penalty without enough benefits. You might re-validate the same parameter (let's say to be not null and a member of the collection) all through the call stack...for 10 times. Does it add anything to code quality? Validate on interface boundary and assert about its correctness! There may be a remote case not handled by your tests (UT and AT), untested by public interface methods and unseen during development? Yes. Do I (usually) want to pay the performance cost for this remote case? **Usually** not.

Comment: Of course there are scenarios where you really want to try your best to recover (even) from programming errors but then code and architecture will be much more complex than a simple if/throw (which BTW...still crashes the application in production and if you don't have a solid well-done exception handling strategy it won't mitigate data loss/data corruption).

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti: when it comes to coding everybody has its own style, so if this is ok for you it's ok for me too. I was just pointing out that what you are doing here is the exact reason for bugs to appear when it comes to released software: "I tested everything in debug so the software will never crash" -> next crash in three, two, one... I'm not a huge fan myself of exceptions, by the way (and about recovering at all), but what you are doing here is let loose a code in production that will end up allowing bad data to be gathered. Now all that you need is an overconfident DBA, et voila'...

Comment: (all IMHO, obviously)

Comment: I see your point but 1) unit testing (and of course acceptance testing) should run with release version on your building machine (but it's much more handy to run them with debug version on development machine). 2) Assertions are not for validation! They do not replace `if`. They're an aid to find programming bugs (as well as logical flaws) during debugging (and while running tests on your local machine). 3) Databases, like any other I/O operation, are a boundary and data MUST be checked at boundaries (OK...obviously there are exceptions to this rule...)

Comment: Imagine you have a public function `PathCombine()`. It will validate its inputs. Imagine that you do everything by yourself and to implement it you have a number of private functions: `HasTrailingPathSeparator()`, `EnsureHasTrailingPathSeparator()`, `AppendPathImpl()`, `IsPathRelative()` and `ExpandRelativePath()` and maybe `TrimPath()`. What's the advantage of revalidating `path1` and `path2` (say...) in each one? SOMETIMES we must re-validate object state and parameters just before performing an operation, imagine an application processing financial transactions...but it's a case, not a rule

Comment: IMO, of course! I love discussions about reliability!

Comment: Visual Studio (all versions) has a really poor support for `Debug.Assert` so I'm also on the side of exceptions. They convey more information then the assert dialog and are easier to analyze.

Comment: Another alternative would be a project like https://github.com/Fody/NullGuard . It may turn on assembly level checks for null arguments on each method invocation. IMO, `fail fast` is a good approach *even if we don't recover*. `fail fast` often helps not making things even worse than they are. If we know, the program is in the bad state, I'd rather crash hard than let it touch memory, filesystem, DB, or external APIs...

Comment: @IgorSoloydenko That 'fail fast and don't recover' mentality is one of the many reasons that a *plethora* of users (including other developers, like myself) get extremely aggravated at current software: I lose hours of work in the Microsoft Office products regularly, because they have the 'fail fast and don't recover' mentality. There are other applications I use that are even worse. You can 'fail fast', but you should **always** try to recover program state. Not doing so is an affront to your users and other developers, regardless of what the program touches.

Comment: @EBrown `I lose hours of work in the Microsoft Office products regularly, because they have the 'fail fast and don't recover' mentality` -- this statement is unjustified. How do you know your favorite MS Office software has not attempted to recover its state? It could be just low quality soft. As soon as the app "knows" it's in broken state, it can not be sure about anything related to its state and recovery can often make things worse than they are. The solution is not in state recovery, but rather in building the mechanisms that reliably prevent state corruption in first place.

Comment: @EBrown the last sentence probably requires clarification. I am specifically talking about things like Redux (or pretty much anythings that is CQRS-based). Of course, CQRS is not panacea, but it way more reliable than the 'ad hoc' state management approaches which are commonly used as an alternative.

Comment: This pattern, while common, doesn't offer a strong guarantee that the class is immutable. The class itself is free to access the private setters. At some point down the road, you may find this method added to the class `public void GoshIReallyNeedToChangeTheEmail(string email) { Email = email; }` The answer with `readonly` fields provides a strong guarantee.

Comment: &ericj no, note that the setter isn't declared. It makes them `readonly` properties. Setters are not just private, they're accessible only in ctor

Answer (score 4):

I would like only to show other possibility how "lock" a variable, but Adriano Repetti shows a really nice work in the other post. So, you also might consider using `readonly` keyword which allows setting to the variable only in the constructor. So this will basically become (plus consider all the other stuff said by Adriano)

```
public class User
{
    public readonly string FirstName;
    public readonly string Surname;
    public readonly string Email;

    public User(string firstName, string surname, string email)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        Surname = surname;
        Email = email;
    }
}
```

---

EDIT: For clarification, I was addressing only the part about immutability. Without any further considerations about interfaces, reflections etc. as that was not asked for. And given "simplicity" of question it seemed a bit like overthinking.

Comment: Except these are now fields and it is generally discouraged to have public fields.

Comment: Final public fields are pretty much exactly the same as using getter-only properties (Although many programmers still react negatively because they have been taught a pattern and haven't reasoned it through themselves--also sometimes it's just easier and safer to blindly follow a pattern).  However, this code has the advantage of making the fact that the fields are intended to be immutable obvious (if they were not read only, one might not think to treat them as immutable when modifying the User class).  The ideal solution would be to add readonly to Adriano Repetti's solution.

Comment: @BillK They are not and this solution has a very important downside namely you won't be able to write an interface for it because interfaces can only have properties and not fields.

Comment: @t3chb0t As I said, the best solution would be to add readonly to the other solution, and your point is valid, but not a situation I've ever encountered.  If I found myself writing an interface for properties I'd have to seriously question my design for a bit.

Comment: Bill, a property with only a getter IS (has) a readonly field as backing store. You can't reassign them outside ctor. Hmmm don't you ever had an interface with one property?! Well, from an academic point of view I agree they don't offer any better incapsulation than fields but I _prefer_ consistency with when I need them to validate (for example) the input.

Comment: @BillK With reflection you can change the value of a field but not the value of a readonly property.

Comment: @Denis Another good point--more immutable :) (My background is mostly Java, but in Java you CAN change a read only (final) field with reflection so I didn't consider that advantage.) On the other hand, when I WANT to use reflection to change a variable, it's often one the author didn't intend to change but I have to anyway, so--tie?

Comment: I would like just to thank anyone who cared to explain why they downvoted so I myself can learn too, about issues with my way of thinking and coding.

Answer (score 2):

The new throw expressions in C# 7 are very nice but unfortunatelly they cannot be used when string must not be null or empty. You can workaround this with a helper extension:

```
public static string NullIfNullOrEmpty(this string str) => string.IsNullOrEmpty(str) ? null : str;
```

so that you may validate the input with:

```
FirstName = firstName.NullIfNullOrEmpty() ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(firstName));
```

and you don't need an additional `if`.

Comment: Technically, you shouldn't throw an `ArgumentNullException` for an empty string, only a null string. It's a fairly unambiguous nomenclature. However, a subclass, perhaps called `StringArgumentNullOrEmptyException` would be caught by anything that catches `ArgumentNullException` as well.

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer an empty string is usally as usefull as a null string so I  usally treat them as one. There is rarely a case where you can continue with an empty string and still get valid results.